# CI4 & WordPress HTACCESS Redirects

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-4

I have a CodeIgniter 4 installation and a WordPress one within the same public directory.

If I set the permalinks to anything but the default ones in WordPress I start getting "redirected to many times" error.

I believe I need to exclude the CI4 htaccess file from the WordPress one, however this is were I and struggling. I have tried various things but still getting the same errors.

The htaccess for the CI4 looks like

Any help would be much appreciated

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine On
# If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
# change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
RewriteBase /

 #RewriteRule ^(WP)($|/) - [L]
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to the front controller, index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# Ensure Authorization header is passed along
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I have

```
RewriteRule ^(wordpress)($|/) - [L]
```

But this did not solve the problem

Comment: "within the same public directory" - Presumably one is in a subdirectory? They aren't literally both in "the same public directory"? What URLs are you using to access these two sites? "redirected to many times" - So what is the redirect loop exactly? Is the site accessible over HTTPS? Why are you specifically checking that `HTTPS` is _off_ in the 2nd rule?

Comment: Yes WP is in a subdirectory. The CI4 app is the main URL, but the WordPress site is /WP/. Yes the site is over HTTPS, this HTACCESS file is the default one from CI4. If it turn on Permalinks in WordPress I then get the redirection error.

Comment: You should have another `.htaccess` file in the WordPress subdirectory (ie. `/WP/.htaccess`). Please add this to your question also.